# Ember computed property for nested array element

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my Ember app, I have a component which has array with attributes like below;

```
secInfoObj.addRows[0].prop-1.value
secInfoObj.addRows[0].prop-2.value

secInfoObj.addRows[1].prop-1.value
secInfoObj.addRows[1].prop-2.value
```

Now I want a computed property which should be triggered whenever the inner prop-1.value or prop-2.value changes.

Not sure how do I add a computed property for such nested properties ?

Comment: Please add more details to question.

Comment: Not sure what details you need...But I just want a computed property to be triggered whenever any of the attribute changes inside that array secInfoObj.addRows

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can watch nested props.  You can watch an array item prop like this

```
Ember.computed('secInfoObj.addRows.@each.prop-1', function() {

})
```

But you cannot watch the value property like this

```
Ember.computed('secInfoObj.addRows.@each.prop-1.value', function() {

})
```

There is more info at https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/